# Fourier transform of sine function and use of Parseval's formula

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Calculate the Fourier transform of the function

$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sin{ax} ,  & |x| \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0, & |x| > \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Hence using Parseval's formula

$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2$  $dx$ $=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2$ $d\xi$,

Show that $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \cos^2(\frac{\pi x}{2})}{(x^2-1)}$ $dx$ $=\frac{\pi ^2}{4}$

---

$F[f(x)]=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2a}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2a}} e^{-i\xi x}.\sin{ax}$ $dx$

$=\frac{1}{2i}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2a}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2a}} e^{-i\xi x}[e^{iax}-e^{-iax}]$ $dx$

$=\frac{1}{2i}[\frac{e^{x(ai-i\xi)}}{ai-i\xi} + \frac{e^{x(-ai-i\xi)}}{ai+i\xi}]^{\frac{\pi}{2a}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2a}}$

Simplifying further,

$\frac{[ai e^{(\frac{\pi i}{2}-\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}+i \xi e^{(\frac{\pi i}{2}-\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}+ai e^{(-\frac{\pi i}{2}-\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}- i \xi e^{(-\frac{\pi i}{2}-\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}- ai e^{(-\frac{\pi i}{2}+\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}- i \xi e^{(-\frac{\pi i}{2}+\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}-ai e^{(\frac{\pi i}{2}+\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}+ i \xi e^{(\frac{\pi i}{2}+\frac{\pi i \xi}{2a})}]}{2i (\xi^2-a^2)}$

I do not know how to proceed longer.

I am used to evaluate F. transform of $\sin ax$ using dirac delta:

$\frac{F[\delta(x+a)-\delta(x-a)]}{2i}=\sin {a \xi}$

I then use symmetry

$ \sin \xi \leftrightarrow 2 \pi .\frac{[\delta(-\xi+a)-\delta(-\xi-a)]}{2i} $

$ \sin \xi \leftrightarrow i \pi \frac{[\delta(\xi+a)-\delta(\xi-a)]}{2i}$ (I ommitted some obvious steps since dirac delta is positive)

Please help. Following that, I should be able to carry forward for the Parseval's formula.

Comment: You can implify a lot further. Use that $e^{\pm i\pi/2}=\pm i$.

Comment: In final I got $-\frac{i}{2(a^2- \xi ^2)}[2 \xi e^{1-\frac{\xi}{a}}+2a e^{1-\frac{\xi}{a}}+ (a- \xi)  (e^{-1-\frac{\xi}{a}}- e^{+1+\frac{\xi}{a}})]$  I do not know what to do further

Comment: That seems to be wrong. How do the $i$ in the exponent disappear? You should still have terms with $e^{\pm \pi i \xi/(2a)}$. Be careful!

Comment: I got it. Thnx. Now for the Parsevals formula: I take a=1; $\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} sin^2 x$ $dx =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac {\xi^2}{(\xi^2-1)^2} \cos^2{\frac{\pi \xi}{2}}$ $d \xi$ I am getting $\pi ^2$ instead of $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$